# We denote scalars with lowercase or with lowercases?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- We denote scalars with lowercase.
- We denote scalars with lowercase**s**.

[Example](http://www.books.aisc.ucla.edu/AICRJStyleSheet.pdf) (let's ignore the space between *lower* and *cases*):

[image: UCLA definition of lowercases]

[*Lowercase*](https://www.google.com/search?q=lowercase) can be a noun:

[image: Google definition of lowercase]

Comment: Have you found any examples of anyone writing "lowercases" like this anywhere?  It looks extremely unnatural to me.   "Lowercase" almost always works more like an adjective than a noun, and we don't pluralize adjectives

Comment: @stangdon example added. Isn't lowercase also a noun?

Comment: But you can't ignore the space in the example, because it changes the meaning -  *lower* is an adjective and *cases* is the noun in the example, not "lowercases".  Technically, I guess you could consider *lowercase* a noun, but in practice, it almost always works like an adjective.  [Look at the relative use of "lowercase" and "lowercases"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lowercase%2Clowercases&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clowercase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clowercases%3B%2Cc0): "lowercases" is almost nonexistent.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks, interesting. I guess this means 1. the most frequent form by far would be "with lower cases"; 2. "with lowercases" is grammatically correct but rarely used; 3. "with lowercase" is ungrammatical?

Comment: @stangdon When you say you need to capitalize the first word of a sentence, you don't necessarily mean you have to capitalize all the letters (alphabets) of the first word. It means you need to capitalize the first letter of the first word. I believe that's why uppercase and lowercase are used only singularly most of the cases.

Comment: @Rathony Good point. Let's assume in that case that the one scalar is denoted with only one character.

Comment: IMO, it doesn't matter whether we're talking about multiple letters or a single letter, the words "uppercase" and "lowercase" are used like adjectives.  For example, "[The word *yes*, for example, is in lowercase, while the word *YES* is in uppercase.](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/lowercase.html)" or "[Result: A string in lowercase.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx)"  The most idiomatic way to phrase the original sentence would be "We denote scalars with lowercase."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say your example is **incomplete**.

> **with** lowercase

might leave the listener asking "lowercase what?" even though the word **lowercase** is implicitly associated with letters.

> **with** lowercase **letters**.

would be a more correct phrasing.

However, a very common way of saying this is

> **in** lowercase

which is often used and natively understandable.
I have never heard **lowercases** used in common conversation.

> We denote scalars **in** lowercase.
>   Scalars are denotes **in** lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase is treated as an uncountable noun, so it would not normally form a plural https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lower_case#English

Therefore use lowercase, not lowercases.